# Are model queries through ReferenceProperty strongly consistent in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I have a SubModel that is connected to Model through ReferenceProperty and I query for all SubModels through ModelEntity.SubModels, is the query strongly consistent?

Answer (score 2):

All queries can only be consistent when utilising an entity group (ie parent key).  If your reference properties are within the same entity group then they will be strongly consistent.

In case you haven't read it, have a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency